# How can I add conditions to a Logic App using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-logic-apps

Using Terraform, I am trying to create a logic app that has 2 actions.

First would be an "azurerm_logic_app_action_custom" that triggers a container.
Second has to be a condition (if statement) that will do an action based on first action output

This is what I has to far and it works:

```
`## Define the Trigger
resource "azurerm_logic_app_trigger_recurrence" "snowcontainer" {
  name         = "${var.env}-scheduled-start"
  time_zone    = "W. Europe Standard Time"
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.snowraw.id
  frequency    = "Day"
  interval     = 1

  schedule {
    at_these_hours   = [1]
    at_these_minutes = [5]
  }
}

## Define the Action
resource "azurerm_logic_app_action_custom" "snowcontainer" {
  name         = "start-${var.env}-snow-raw"
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.snowraw.id
  body = <<BODY
{
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['aci']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "post",
        "path": "/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent('${var.subscription_id}')}/resourceGroups/@{encodeURIComponent('${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}')}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/@{encodeURIComponent('${azurerm_container_group.snowraw.name}')}/start",
        "queries": {
            "x-ms-api-version": "2019-12-01"
        }
    },
    "runAfter": {},
    "type": "ApiConnection"
    }
BODY
}`
```

But I need to add the condition action after the Azure Container trigger action and I don't know how....

```
`## Define the Action
resource "azurerm_logic_app_action_custom" "condition" {
  name         = "condition-snow-raw"
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.snowraw.id

  body = <<BODY
{
   "expression": {
     "and": [
       {
        "contains": [
           "@body('start-dev-snow-raw')",
           "error"
         ]
       }
     ]
   },
   "actions": {
  },
  "else": {
    "actions": {
    }
   },
  "runAfter": {},    ##probably here I will have to mention the previous action
  "type": "If"
  }
BODY
}`
```

Can anyone help me please?

In the end I need an logic app with 2 actions, One will be the container instance trigger and second will be the condition action

In the end, I need a logic app that has 2 actions. First will be the azure container instance trigger and second will be the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Adding conditions to a Logic App using Terraform.

To add a conditional action in Terraform that operates based on the output of the initial Azure Container Instance trigger action, you must specify the `runAfter` block within the conditional action. This block determines which actions must be completed before the current action can execute. In this instance, you would set the condition to evaluate only after the custom action that initiates the container has been executed.

You also need to specify that the `condition` action runs after the completion of the `start-dev-snow-raw` action. This is accomplished by correctly setting the `runAfter` property. I have tried the configuration with the necessary changes, and it works as expected.

***My terraform configuration:***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

variable "env" {
  description = "Environment (dev, qa, prod)"
}

variable "subscription_id" {
  description = "Azure Subscription ID"
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "Name of the existing resource group"
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "existing" {
  name = var.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_container_group" "snowraw" {
    name = "testvk"
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.name
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "snowraw" {
  name                = "snowraw-workflow-${var.env}"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.name
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_trigger_recurrence" "snowcontainer" {
  name         = "${var.env}-scheduled-start"
  time_zone    = "W. Europe Standard Time"
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.snowraw.id
  frequency    = "Day"
  interval     = 1

  schedule {
    at_these_hours   = [1]
    at_these_minutes = [5]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_action_custom" "snowcontainer" {
  name         = "start-dev-snow-raw"
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.snowraw.id
  body = <<BODY
{
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['aci']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "post",
        "path": "/subscriptions/${var.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.name}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/${data.azurerm_container_group.snowraw.name}/start",
        "queries": {
            "x-ms-api-version": "2019-12-01"
        }
    },
    "runAfter": {},
    "type": "ApiConnection"
}
BODY
}


resource "azurerm_logic_app_action_custom" "condition" {
  name         = "condition-dev-raw"
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.snowraw.id
  body = <<BODY
{
  "type": "InitializeVariable",
  "inputs": {
    "variables": [
      {
        "name": "IsError",
        "type": "boolean",
        "value": "@contains(body('start-${var.env}-snow-raw'), 'error')"
      }
    ]
  },
  "runAfter": {
    "start-dev-snow-raw": ["Succeeded"]
  }
}
BODY
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is amazing. such a detailed answer. Thank you so much for your effort. I tested the code and it works. I replaced the variable with a "type: If" . 
Thank you!

Comment: Good to know it worked for you.!